# How to overload copy assignment operator for const data members?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

ERROR MSG:

> error: passing 'const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

I have a class like this and need to build a copy assignment operator where the `name_` must be `const`.

How to overcome the error?

```cpp
class Station
{
private: 
    const string name_;
    Station& operator=(const Station& station) { 
        name_ = station.name_; //ERROR
        return *this;
    }
public:
    Station(string name): 
        name_(name){};
    Station(const Station& station): name_(station.name_){};
```

Comment: maybe remove the ```const``` from the name declaration ```const string name_```. It may be that when you try to assign station.name to it you violate your own rule of this member to be constant.

Comment: "_I have a class like this and need to build a copy assignment operator where the `name_` must be const_" - One of those requirements has to be dropped - unless you make a copy constructor/assignment operator that copies everything but  `name_`.

Comment: From a design perspective, you don't.    Having a `const` member means that it is not possible to assign that member after it is initialised.   But the purpose of an assignment operator is generally to assign all members of the class after they have been initialised.    If you must supply an `operator=()` for a class with a `const` member you must (1) justify such a broken design   (2)  implement the `operator=()` so it assigns other members, but not the `const` ones.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Presumably the copy constructor should copy `name_`, since its only other choice would be to make it empty. But if the class does that, it will violate the Principle of Least Surprise.

Comment: Thanks @Peter ! for the clarification. Yes I can understand I was wrong from design perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the const casting  like so

```cpp
Station& operator=(const Station& station) { 
        const_cast<std::string> name_ = station.name_; // Work
        return *this;
    }
```